# hi, my tor browser can't establish a connection

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

```
7/27/2017 13:56:10 PM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
7/27/2017 13:56:10 PM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
7/27/2017 13:56:10 PM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
7/27/2017 13:56:10 PM.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
7/27/2017 13:56:10 PM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
7/27/2017 13:56:10 PM.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
7/27/2017 13:56:11 PM.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
7/27/2017 13:56:11 PM.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
7/27/2017 13:56:11 PM.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
7/27/2017 13:56:14 PM.000 [WARN] Received directory with skewed time (DIRSERV:199.254.238.53:443): It seems that our clock is ahead by 1 days, 1 hours, 58 minutes, or that theirs is behind. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings. 
7/27/2017 13:56:14 PM.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 45%: Asking for relay descriptors 
7/27/2017 13:56:14 PM.000 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We need more microdescriptors: we have 4719/6964, and can only build 30% of likely paths. (We have 65% of guards bw, 66% of midpoint bw, and 70% of exit bw = 30% of path bw.) 
7/27/2017 13:56:14 PM.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 64%: Loading relay descriptors 
7/27/2017 13:56:16 PM.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 72%: Loading relay descriptors 
7/27/2017 13:56:16 PM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 78%: Loading relay descriptors 
7/27/2017 13:56:16 PM.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network 
7/27/2017 13:56:17 PM.000 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop 0 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 

                             ---- Message spams... ----

7/27/2017 13:59:16 PM.200 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
7/27/2017 13:59:16 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
7/27/2017 13:59:16 PM.200 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
7/27/2017 13:59:17 PM.000 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Comment: `...It seems that our clock is ahead by 1 days, 1 hours, 58 minutes, or that theirs is behind...` Check that your date, time and timezone are set correctly.